# Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'f_name' cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

I am getting this error.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
> constraint violation: 1048 Column 'f_name' cannot be null (SQL: insert
> into `userdetails` (`id`, `f_name`, `l_name`, `company_name`,
> `mobile_number`, `email`, `address`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
> values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 2020-09-07 05:25:53, 2020-09-07
> 05:25:53))

This is my controller.

**CheckoutController.php**

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Userdetail;


class CheckoutController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $userdetail = Userdetail::get();
        return view ('checkout')->with(compact('userdetail'));
      
    }
   
    public function create()
    {
       return view('checkout.create');
    }


   
    public function store(Request $request, Userdetail $userdetail)
    {

        $userdetail-> id = $request-> id;
        $userdetail-> f_name = $request-> f_name;
        $userdetail-> l_name = $request-> l_name;
        $userdetail-> company_name = $request-> company_name;
        $userdetail-> mobile_number = $request-> mobile_number;
        $userdetail-> email = $request-> email;
        $userdetail-> address = $request-> address;
        
        $userdetail->save();
        return redirect()->route('checkout.store');
       
    }

    
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

  
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

   
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

   
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This is my blade file.

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('checkout.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <div class="pb-7 mb-7">
            <!-- Title -->
            <div class="border-bottom border-color-1 mb-5">
                <h3 class="section-title mb-0 pb-2 font-size-25">Billing details</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- End Title -->

            <!-- Billing Form -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <!-- Input -->
                    <div class="js-form-message mb-6">
                        <label class="form-label">
                        Recipient First Name
                            <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f_name" placeholder="Jack" aria-label="Jack" required="" data-msg="Please enter receipint first name." data-error-class="u-has-error" data-success-class="u-has-success" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Input -->
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <!-- Input -->
                    <div class="js-form-message mb-6">
                        <label class="form-label">
                        Recipient  Last Name
                            <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="l_name" placeholder="Jack" aria-label="Jack" required="" data-msg="Please enter receipint last name." data-error-class="u-has-error" data-success-class="u-has-success" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Input -->
                </div>

                <div class="w-100"></div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <!-- Input -->
                    <div class="js-form-message mb-6">
                        <label class="form-label">
                            Company name (optional)
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company_name" placeholder="Company Name" aria-label="Company Name" data-msg="Please enter a company name." data-error-class="u-has-error" data-success-class="u-has-success">
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Input -->
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <!-- Input -->
                    <div class="js-form-message mb-6">
                        <label class="form-label">
                        Mobile No
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile_number" placeholder="+1 (062) 109-9222" aria-label="+1 (062) 109-9222" required="" data-msg="Please enter your mobile number." data-error-class="u-has-error" data-success-class="u-has-success">
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Input -->
                </div>
            
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <!-- Input -->
                    <div class="js-form-message mb-6">
                        <label class="form-label">
                            Email address
                            <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="jackwayley@gmail.com" aria-label="jackwayley@gmail.com" required="" data-msg="Please enter a valid email address." data-error-class="u-has-error" data-success-class="u-has-success">
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Input -->
                </div>

                <div class="w-100"></div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <!-- Input -->
                    <div class="js-form-message mb-6">
                        <label class="form-label">
                            Address
                            <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="91,Galle Road, Colo0mbo 04" aria-label="91,Galle Road, Colo0mbo 04" required="" data-msg="Please enter a valid email address." data-error-class="u-has-error" data-success-class="u-has-success">
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Input -->
                </div>
                                        

                <div class="w-100"></div>

            </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary-dark-w btn-block btn-pill font-size-20 mb-3 py-3">Place order</button>
         
        </div>
</form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('/checkout', 'CheckoutController')->middleware('auth');
```

**Userdetail** model

```
<?php
    
    namespace App;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Userdetail extends Model
    {
        //
    }
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: I think, you did not add `f_name` on `$fillable` on your **Userdetail** model, or `$request->f_name;` returns null

Comment: Paste your model code

Comment: @sta Fillable wouldn't matter in this case since the OP is explicitly setting the attribute rather than using the `fill()` method (or a method that uses `fill` behind the scenes).

Comment: Did the `f_name` input have a value before you submitted the form or was it blank?

Comment: I change my code as above and it works like a charm. Do I need to add anything in the model?

Comment: @sta I change my code as above and it works like a charm. Do I need to add anything to the model?@Faizan Fayaz

Comment: @Zeenath, in your case fillable is enough to save your data on the database. Their are some other method like hidden, guared. You can see the official doc about all method in eloquent https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel the **save()** method is an eloquent method. In eloquent ORM, **$fillable** attribute is an array containing all those fields of table which can be filled using mass-assignment. Mass assignment refers to sending an array to the model to directly create a new record in Database.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'f_name', 
    'l_name', 
    'company_name',
    'mobile_number',
    'email',
    'address',
];
```

See the official documentation of [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)